# CSS Header image not showing

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code to show an image on the header, but the image is not showing.

```
#header {
    margin:          0 auto;
    width:           830px;
    height:          250px;    
    background-image: url("images/banner.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Problem is, nothing is showing.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to check your image route.

Comment: do you have errors in the console?

Comment: Without knowing the actual path of the css file and the image file, I would assume that the path to the image in the css file is not correct and may need to be modified for the css file to read the image.

Comment: Also check that your header tag has `id="header"` since you're using the `#header` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is OK, except you path to image, see:

```css
#header {
    margin:          0 auto;
    width:           830px;
    height:          250px;    
    background-image: url("http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/2012/12/img_logo_blue.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

If you will share the structure of your project, I can help you to write the right path to image.

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes :

1. Verify that your the html element has an **id** "header" (not class and not a header element).
2. The image path is **relative** to the css file, so to match your css code you should find a directory called images in the same directory as your css file.
3. Check that the image file banner.jpg actually **exists**.

also, check your browser console for error messages.